# SQL Query to Roll Up Data from the Last 7 Days

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's assume I have a table structure like this.

```
CheckIn
- int checkInId pk
- int companyPositionId
- Date checkInDate
```

Let's say I want to get a count of all check ins for the last 7 days from a given date. What would be the best way to do this? Right now I'm making a query for each of the 7 dates AND the company positions. Currently this is too slow because there could be many companyPositions * 7 days. How can I roll this up into one query?

Would it be easiest to generate the last 7 days dates and construct a long query? Could I then group count by a date range for each of the 7 days?

An ideal result back could look like:

```
companyPositionId, date1Count, date2Count, date3Count, date4Count, date5Count, date6Count.
```

**Example Data:**

```
checkInId | companyPositionId | checkInDate
1         | 1                 | 1970-01-01
2         | 1                 | 1970-01-02
3         | 1                 | 1970-01-03
4         | 1                 | 1970-01-04
5         | 1                 | 1970-01-05
6         | 1                 | 1970-01-06
7         | 1                 | 1970-01-07
8         | 2                 | 1970-01-01
9         | 2                 | 1970-01-02
10        | 2                 | 1970-01-03
11        | 2                 | 1970-01-04
12        | 2                 | 1970-01-05
13        | 2                 | 1970-01-06
14        | 2                 | 1970-01-07*
15        | 2                 | 1970-01-07*
```

My current query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM CheckIn
  WHERE (startDate) <= (inputDate) 
    AND (inputDate) <= (endDate)
    AND companyPositionId = (companyPositionId);
```

I then loop through each startDate/endDate that is generated from the beginning of the day and end of that day. And then each of the companyPositionId's.

**Ideal result:**

```
companyPositionId | date1Count | date2Count | date3Count | date4Count | date5Count | date6Count | date7Count
1                 | 1          | 1          | 1          | 1          | 1          | 1          | 1
2                 | 1          | 1          | 1          | 1          | 1          | 1          | 2
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Show us your current query, some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh This is to improve the way I'm currently querying because now I'm making many queries. Do you still want to see the query I send for 7 date ranges for every "position".

Comment: @RyanDawkins yes show the query and also some raw data to use.

Comment: It's unclear what your desired result is from the position column. The question currently seems like it can be solved simply by selecting count check-in and grouping by date.

Comment: RE: Current Query: When looking at your result, what are you doing with each dataset after, is there aggregation involved once you have them?

Comment: @CiucaS
I've added example data and now an example ideal result.

Comment: Yes currently I'm having to aggregate it all to get the "ideal result" I just added to the post. @MaxSorin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `PIVOT` command, or with conditional `SUM`s:

```
DECLARE @my_date DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

SELECT
    companyPositionId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(checkInDate AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -7, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date1Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(checkInDate AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -6, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date2Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(checkInDate AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -5, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date3Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(checkInDate AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -4, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date4Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(checkInDate AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -3, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date5Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(checkInDate AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -2, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date6Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(checkInDate AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date7Count
FROM
    CheckIn
WHERE
    checkInDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    companyPositionId
```

If your checkInDate has a time component then you'll need to account for that.

I declared the `@my_date` variable just to avoid having to repeat that expression in the query a bunch of times, but you could replace the variable with that expression and it would work as well. You could also use `BETWEEN` which might have better performance since the optimizer could then potentially use an index on your `checkInDate`. Just calculate midnight/11:59:59 of each of the days instead of looking for equality.

Comment: Currently it does have a time component. Can I strip it out when doing the comparison?

Comment: Yes, if you just cast the column as a `DATE` then that should do it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Does this group all of the companyPositions into one row? This seems to be doing that for me.

Comment: If you're using `GROUP BY companyPositionId` then each ID should have its own row.

Comment: Turns out I was looking at a stage website and a dev database. The query was correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at

```
Declare @d date= '2016-05-05';  -- parameter, we need this day and six previous

Select
  companyPositionId
  ,date1Count = count(case checkInDate when @d then checkInId end) 
  ,date2Count = count(case checkInDate when dateadd(d,-1,@d) then checkInId end)
  --...
from checkIn
where checkInDate between dateadd(d,-6,@d) and @d
group by companyPositionId
order by companyPositionId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #checkin (

 checkInId INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
 companyPositionId int, 
 checkInDate DATE
)

DECLARE @counter INT = 100
WHILE @counter > 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO #checkin
        ( companyPositionId, checkInDate )
VALUES  ( RAND() * 10 + 1, -- 10 possible companies? 
          DATEADD(day, RAND()*-7, GETDATE())  -- random days in the last 2 weeks
          )

SET @counter = @counter - 1
END
```

Logic starts here:

```
DECLARE 
    @now DATETIME   = GETDATE(),
    @days INT       = -7 -- Our interval of interest
```

This logic is partially borrowed from Bogdan Sahlean, his results were getting all '1' for me, so I changed the `dayNum` calculation

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  companyPositionId, checkInId, 1 + CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,checkInDate, @now) AS INT) AS DayNum
    FROM    #CheckIn
    WHERE   checkInDate BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, @days, @now) AS DATE) AND @now  
) AS ps -- Pivot source
PIVOT ( COUNT(checkInId) FOR DayNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]) ) AS p


DROP TABLE #checkin
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick pivot example assuming you're looking for the previous 7 days of the `@inputDate`. This should work even with the time component since it goes off a `DATEDIFF` with days only.

```
DECLARE @InputDate DATE = '1/8/1970'
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(DD, checkInDate, @InputDate) AS DaysAgo FROM @CheckIns
)
    SELECT
        companyPositionId,
        SUM([7]) AS date1Count,
        SUM([6]) AS date2Count,
        SUM([5]) AS date3Count,
        SUM([4]) AS date4Count,
        SUM([3]) AS date5Count,
        SUM([2]) AS date6Count,
        SUM([1]) AS date7Count -- Reversed columns since you wanted 7 to be most recent day 
    FROM CTE
        PIVOT (COUNT(checkInId) FOR DaysAgo IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) PVT
    GROUP BY
        companyPositionId
```

This gives the following results matching your desired output:

```
companyPositionId date1Count  date2Count  date3Count  date4Count  date5Count  date6Count  date7Count
----------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1                 1           1           1           1           1           1           1
2                 1           1           1           1           1           1           2
```